# ACF Relationship - Get Parent's Post Object

Tags: posts, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I've a few post that have ACF relationship field set up :

```
- Post A
- Post A1
- Post A2
- Post A3
```

**Post A** have a relationship that link to :
**Post A1,A2 & A3**...

Post A1,A2,A3 have their own post templates,

But inside the post templates, can I manage to get **Post A's Title**?

Because I don't want hardcoded Post A's title on Post A1,A2,A3's fields.

I'd tried [this solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-custom-fields-field-from-parent-page-into-child-page), but seems can't retrieve parent A's post object...

Below is my custom field settings on **Post A**'s category, to select children products relationship *( which is A1,A2,A3 that mentioned above )* :

[image]

Thankyou

Comment: How is the relationship stored? Does ACF insert meta against Post A1, A2, A3 that says the parent post is "Post A" or?

Comment: @userabuser I setup a relationship custom field on Post A. Then when i on Post A, I able to stored A1,A2,A3's post.

The relationship fields seems doesn't have any settings for me to define parent / children post meta? I edited my question and posted a ss.... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ACF Relationships doesn't set any relationship as a parent or child,you'd be better of just getting the title from your post.

You could simply get the ID of your A page: `the_title( '43' );` and output it like this, or if the post *is actually a parent*, you could simply do `the_title( wp_get_post_parent_id() );` on your child template.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the case covered in the ACF documentation's [Doctors and Locations example](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/).

- The relationship is stored on the Post A, as a list of post IDs for A1, A2, A3, and not the other way around.
- To find A from A1, you'll need to query all posts for a meta value of the relationship that has value A1's post ID
- But these are stored as a PHP serialised array. The article suggests a LIKE query for `"123"` where 123 is A1's post ID.

This is pretty horrible IMO but may be the only way without e.g. automatically reflecting the relationship into A1/2/3's post meta somewhere on save. And conceivably there could be a second post B that also has the same relationship to A1, so there's no guarantee you'll only get one result from the reverse search. (However assuming the relationship is stored as a serialised array of numbers only the query should be accurate at least: I can't see any other way for a quoted integer to exist in that string.)